# Hello = I say hello -> correct?

Tags: exclamatives

Could I consider that all the exclamation is the abbreviation form of the S-V-O structure?

No = I say no / It's no

Hi = I say hi

Wow = I say wow

There = There you go / There it is / etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a very useful analysis:

If "No" means *I say "no",  then "I say 'no'" means *I say "I say 'no'."*  (which means *I say 'I say ''I say '''now'''''''*... and so on.)  It doesn't really help understand.

Instead consider the function that these exclamations have:

"No" is used to reject, deny or disallow something.

"Hi" is used to greet

"Wow!" is used to indicate surprise